# GIS dataset with latitude, longitude, and elevation

Tags: elevation

Websites such as this one: https://gisgeography.com/best-free-gis-data-sources-raster-vector/ 
have many references to elevation data. They are all in `*.jpg` or other image format, however. What I need is simply a flat text file with lat/long/elevation as real numbers.
I suppose there is a way to find or extract such data. Any pointers?

Comment: DEM/DTM are often supplied as raster data, mostly tiff. The conversion from tiff to polygon to point data is rather easy (`contours` tool). Sometimes DEM/DTM are supplied as xyz, depends on you budget, your area of interest etc.

Comment: If Finland is OK as a test area then download elevation data in ASCII grid format from https://tiedostopalvelu.maanmittauslaitos.fi/tp/kartta/. With gdal_translate https://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html you can make a conversion from image formats to for example xyz https://www.gdal.org/frmt_xyz.html or to ASCII grid https://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html.

Comment: Hi, were you able to get this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My common tool to convert raster data to XYZ is in GRASS GIS
[r.out.xyz](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass77/manuals/r.out.xyz.html)

QGIS processing (at least v2.18) offers GDAL module
[gdal2xyz](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_conversion/gdal2xyz.html)

But be aware, larger DEM files can produce a really large TEXT files.